# I am trying to make an embed in discord.py but it always throws an error that 'await' outside function

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a hug command when a user mention another user, but it shows a syntax error that  `'await' is outside function`.

Here is the code :

```py
    @client.command()
    async def hug(ctx, member):
        username = ctx.message.author.display_name
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = f'{username} has sent a hug to {member}!',
            description = "comforting isn't it <3", 
            color = 0x83B5E3
        )
        embed.set_image(url='https://tenor.com/N4Sj.gif')
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: your code seems to have indention problem. try to fix it or please update the question with right code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to have couple of problems.

First is the indention issue and second is you need to escape `'` using `\`.

Try the following:

```
       async def hug(ctx, member):
          username = ctx.message.author.display_name
          embed = discord.Embed(title = (f'{username} has sent a hug to {member}!'), 
                         description = ('comforting isn\'t it <3'), color = 0x83B5E3)
          image = ('https://tenor.com/N4Sj.gif')
          embed.set_image(url=image)
          await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Ok so this works and the bot comes online but it doesn't respond to the command. its prefix is s!.

Comment: You have also assigned `image` to a tuple by enclosing it into `()`. Try to set image as a string: `image = 'https://tenor.com/N4Sj.gif'`

Comment: I have one question..which line is the command trigger of the bot? Im new to this 

Comment: That would be the send method being called. Please consider accepting the answer if it resolved your question.